# Cant interpolate specific string format in Ruby

Tags: ruby, string

In using a 3rd party web service, I need to loop through an array and make requests.  Without using the term variable, this code works.

```
top_5 = get_top_searches[0..4]
counts = []
top_5.each do |term|
 current_count = @client.request(
    'segmentation',
    event:      "Performed search",
    from_date:  (Date.today - 30.days).strftime("%Y-%-m-%-d"),
    to_date:    Date.today.strftime("%Y-%-m-%-d"),
    where:      'properties["keywords"] == "dogs"'
  )
  counts << [term, current_count]
end
counts
```

However, I need `"dogs"` to be the variable within a loop. Here is a list of strings that **Do Not** work. (the ["keywords"] must be double quoted)

```
'properties["keywords"] == "#{term}"'
"properties[\"keywords\"] == #{term}"
"properties['keywords'] == #{term}"
"'properties["keywords"] == #{term}'"
"'properties[\"keywords\"] == #{term}'"
```

I'm out of ideas. How can I format this string so that ["keywords"] is double quoted, the variable is interpolated, and most likely, the outer quotes are single?

Comment: What's wrong with your second option, `"properties[\"keywords\"] == #{term}"`? Is it just that the interpolated variable needs to be in quotes too, i.e. `"properties[\"keywords\"] == \"#{term}\""`?

Comment: Hey! That actually worked! The variable had to be in escaped quotes as well

Comment: Your first option was spot on, except that interpolation doesn't work with single quotes in Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

Your first option is close, except that interpolation doesn't work in single-quoted strings in Ruby. `"properties[\"keywords\"] == \"#{term}\""` will get you there, since double quotes are the order of the day.

Answer (score 0):

> Here is a list of strings that Do Not work. (the ["keywords"] must be double quoted)

```
'properties["keywords"] == "#{term}"'
"properties[\"keywords\"] == #{term}"
```

The second one works:

```
['dogs', 'cats', 'monkeys'].each do |term|
  puts "properties[\"keywords\"] == #{term}"
end

--output:--
properties["keywords"] == dogs
properties["keywords"] == cats
properties["keywords"] == monkeys
```

Well, I guess you need to add double quotes around `#{term}`:

```
['dogs', 'cats', 'monkeys'].each do |term|
  puts "properties[\"keywords\"] == \"#{term}\""
end

--output:--
properties["keywords"] == "dogs"
properties["keywords"] == "cats"
properties["keywords"] == "monkeys"
```

But you rarely(if ever) have to escape quotes in ruby:

```
%Q{properties["keywords"] == "#{term}"}
```

`%Q{}` acts like double quotes, and you can use any delimiter, e.g. `%Q[], %Q||, %Q**,` etc.

> the outer quotes are single?

Both single and double quotes are String constructors.  Ruby could care less which one you use--they both create Strings.  There is no such thing as a String with single quotes.  If the String you want to create actually has to have `string[0] == "'"` and `string[-1] == "'"`, then you can do this:

```
['dogs', 'cats', 'monkeys'].each do |term|
  puts %Q{'properties["keywords"] == "#{term}"'}
end

--output:--
'properties["keywords"] == "dogs"'
'properties["keywords"] == "cats"'
'properties["keywords"] == "monkeys"'
```

However, that is NOT the same thing as:

```
where: 'properties["keywords"] == "dogs"'
```

The first character in that string is a `p` and the last character in that string is `"`.